# Scala - Dealing with null JSON objects

Tags: json, scala

So I'm parsing JSON in scala. I've got an object which occasionally is null. How should I deal with this?

I would think that `if (json.get("object") != null) {...}` would work, but it doesn't.

This is code I've been experimenting with:

```
import org.json._

val json: JSONObject = new JSONObject("{\"object\": null}")

if (json.get("object") != null) {
    println("The object is not null") //This like is executed
} else {
    println("the object is null") This line is not executed
}

println(json.getString("object")) //This line returns "org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["object"] not a string."
```

So how can I avoid null pointer exceptions when parsing JSON?

Comment: for initalization, use JSONObject.NULL rather than _null_

Comment: for checking against _null_ values use `public boolean isNull(java.lang.String key)`

Comment: JSONObject.NULL worked, thank you.

Comment: posting as answer, accept it, so that it is useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for initalization, use `JSONObject.NULL` rather than `null`

for checking against `null` values use `public boolean isNull(java.lang.String key)`